# Can I use SQLCLR stored procedure to update a column of a database table

Tags: sql-server, encryption, c#-4.0, sql-server-2012, sqlclr

I wanted to update the values of a few columns of a database table, using queries or stored procedure, but wanted to use my C# library to alter the value.

For ex, I want the columns A,B,C of table T to be replaced with `Encrypt(A)`, `Encrypt(B)` and `Encrypt(C)` where `Encrypt` is a part of a C# library.

I could have done it in a simple console application, but I have to do this process for a lot of columns in lot of tables. Could I use some SQLCLR stored procedure/query to do this process in SQL Server Management Studio?

It will be really great if someone could assist in this.

```
public class SP
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction()]
    public static void Enc()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {            
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlCommand command1;

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {                
                command = new SqlCommand("SELECT " + tableFieldArray[i, 1].ToString() + " FROM " + tableFieldArray[i, 0].ToString(), connection);

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();                

                using (reader)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (!reader.IsDBNull(0) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.GetString(0)))
                        {                            
                            //SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Data = " + reader.GetString(0) + "; Encrypted = " + Encrypt(reader.GetString(0)));
                            SqlContext.Pipe.Send("UPDATE " + tableFieldArray[i, 0].ToString() + " SET "
                                                                 + tableFieldArray[i, 1].ToString() + " = '" + Encrypt(reader.GetString(0)) + "' "
                                                                 + "WHERE " + tableFieldArray[i, 1].ToString() + " = '" + reader.GetString(0) + "'");                             
                            //query = "UPDATE " + tableFieldArray[i, 0].ToString() + " SET "
                            //                                     + tableFieldArray[i, 1].ToString() + " = '" + Encrypt(reader.GetString(0)) + "' "
                            //                                     + "WHERE " + tableFieldArray[i, 1].ToString() + " = '" + reader.GetString(0) + "'";                                                                                        
                            command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE " + tableFieldArray[i, 0].ToString() + " SET "
                                                                 + tableFieldArray[i, 1].ToString() + " = '" + Encrypt(reader.GetString(0)) + "' "
                                                                 + "WHERE " + tableFieldArray[i, 1].ToString() + " = '" + reader.GetString(0) + "'",connection);
                       }                    
                   }
                }

                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(query , connection);
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }

             connection.Close();
          }
       }

       public static string Encrypt(string TextFromForm)
       {
          //implementation
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: **Exact duplicate** of [Can I use SQLCLR stored procedure to update a column of a database table ( using some compiled dll)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502697/can-i-use-sqlclr-stored-procedure-to-update-a-column-of-a-database-table-using) - please **don't** keep asking the same question over and over again! (the other one was just 40 minutes ago ......)

Comment: @marc_s  , i am new to stack , dont knwo where to close the previous one from, my earlier question got downvoted (without any explanation) even before i could gather code and make edits on it. so i posted a new one thinking previos one will not be considered.  this was totally unintentional. It takes time to draft a clear question

Comment: Shweta, this one can be closed. I am already answering the other one so you don't need to worry about that. I will copy my answer updates to the other question.

Comment: Well, one recommendation: draft the question **off-line** in your favourite text editor. Indent code and sample data sections by four spaces - that's really all it takes. Once you're done - **then** post it here to avoid these kind of negative experiences from happening again

Comment: i am figuring out where to do  that from .. @srutzky

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, i sjall do so from now on, how to close the question though?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason this question is a complete duplicate of ( [Can I use SQLCLR stored procedure to update a column of a database table ( using some compiled dll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502697/can-i-use-sqlclr-stored-proc-to-update-a-column-of-a-database-table-using-some) ), but assuming that other one will be closed (it should be), my answer is the same:

---

You *can* use SQLCLR to call encryption from C#, though this is the wrong approach. If you need to do a custom algorithm, you should encapsulate that into a SQLCLR function so that it can be used in an UPDATE statement or even an INSERT or SELECT or anywhere.  Something like:

```cs
public class SP
{
  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
  public static SqlString EncryptByAES(SqlString TextToEncrypt)
  {
     return DoSomething(TextToEncrypt.Value);
  }
}
```

Then you can use that function as follows:

```sql
UPDATE tb
SET    tb.FieldA = EncryptByAES(tb.FieldA)
FROM   dbo.TableName tb
WHERE  tb.FieldA some_test_to_determine_that_FieldA_is_not_alreay_encrypted;
```

**BUT**, before you write a custom encryption algorithm, you might want to check out the several built-in paired ENCRYPTBY / DECRYPTBY functions that might do exactly what you need:

- [ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186950.aspx) / [DECRYPTBYASYMKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189507.aspx)
- [ENCRYPTBYCERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188061.aspx) / [DECRYPTBYCERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178601.aspx)
- [ENCRYPTBYKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx) / [DECRYPTBYKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181860.aspx)
- [ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190357.aspx) / [DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188910.aspx)

Comment: yes it is, i am new to stackoverflow and thought my question would not be looked upon because it was downvoted without any explanation even before I could gather code to be added to it. Thanks a ton for responding.

Comment: how do i use these inbuilt encrypt/decrypt methods? I am using AES managed class, would that be available in it?

Comment: @ShwetaSaxena I have updated with links to the built-in functions. If none of those work for you, the structure I posted for a basic function would be the way to go.